# The reason behind back-off strategy for spin lock

Tags: c++, assembly, cpu-architecture, lock-free, compare-and-swap

I'm looking at the spin lock implementation in JVM HotSpot from OpenJDK12. Here is how it is implemented (comments preserved):

```
// Polite TATAS spinlock with exponential backoff - bounded spin.
// Ideally we'd use processor cycles, time or vtime to control
// the loop, but we currently use iterations.
// All the constants within were derived empirically but work over
// over the spectrum of J2SE reference platforms.
// On Niagara-class systems the back-off is unnecessary but
// is relatively harmless.  (At worst it'll slightly retard
// acquisition times).  The back-off is critical for older SMP systems
// where constant fetching of the LockWord would otherwise impair
// scalability.
//
// Clamp spinning at approximately 1/2 of a context-switch round-trip.
// See synchronizer.cpp for details and rationale.

int Monitor::TrySpin(Thread * const Self) {
  if (TryLock())    return 1;
  if (!os::is_MP()) return 0;

  int Probes  = 0;
  int Delay   = 0;
  int SpinMax = 20;
  for (;;) {
    intptr_t v = _LockWord.FullWord;
    if ((v & _LBIT) == 0) {
      if (Atomic::cmpxchg (v|_LBIT, &_LockWord.FullWord, v) == v) {
        return 1;
      }
      continue;
    }

    SpinPause();

    // Periodically increase Delay -- variable Delay form
    // conceptually: delay *= 1 + 1/Exponent
    ++Probes;
    if (Probes > SpinMax) return 0;

    if ((Probes & 0x7) == 0) {
      Delay = ((Delay << 1)|1) & 0x7FF;
      // CONSIDER: Delay += 1 + (Delay/4); Delay &= 0x7FF ;
    }

    // Stall for "Delay" time units - iterations in the current implementation.
    // Avoid generating coherency traffic while stalled.
    // Possible ways to delay:
    //   PAUSE, SLEEP, MEMBAR #sync, MEMBAR #halt,
    //   wr %g0,%asi, gethrtime, rdstick, rdtick, rdtsc, etc. ...
    // Note that on Niagara-class systems we want to minimize STs in the
    // spin loop.  N1 and brethren write-around the L1$ over the xbar into the L2$.
    // Furthermore, they don't have a W$ like traditional SPARC processors.
    // We currently use a Marsaglia Shift-Xor RNG loop.
    if (Self != NULL) {
      jint rv = Self->rng[0];
      for (int k = Delay; --k >= 0;) {
        rv = MarsagliaXORV(rv);
        if (SafepointMechanism::should_block(Self)) return 0;
      }
      Self->rng[0] = rv;
    } else {
      Stall(Delay);
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/runtime/mutex.cpp#l331)

Where `Atomic::cmpxchg` implemented on x86 as

```
template<>
template<typename T>
inline T Atomic::PlatformCmpxchg<8>::operator()(T exchange_value,
                                                T volatile* dest,
                                                T compare_value,
                                                atomic_memory_order /* order */) const {
  STATIC_ASSERT(8 == sizeof(T));
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("lock cmpxchgq %1,(%3)"
                        : "=a" (exchange_value)
                        : "r" (exchange_value), "a" (compare_value), "r" (dest)
                        : "cc", "memory");
  return exchange_value;
}
```

[Link to source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/atomic_linux_x86.hpp#l95)

The thing that I don't understand is the reason behind the backoff on "older SMP" systems. It was said in the commnets that

> The back-off is critical for older SMP systems where constant fetching
>   of the LockWord would otherwise impair scalability.

The reason I can imagine is on older SMP systems when fetching and then CASing the `LockWord` bus lock is always asserted (not cache lock). As it is said in the Intel Manual Vol 3. 8.1.4:

> For the Intel486 and Pentium processors, the `LOCK#` signal is always 
>   asserted on the bus during a `LOCK` operation, even if the area of
>   memory being locked is cached in the processor. For the P6 and more
>   recent processor families, if the area of memory being locked during a
>   `LOCK` operation is cached in the processor that is performing the `LOCK`
>   operation as write-back memory and is completely contained in a cache
>   line, the processor may not assert the `LOCK#` signal on the bus.

Is that the actual reason? Or what is that?

Comment: I don't think they're talking about x86 at all, and almost certainly not primitive x86 before PPro that can just take a cache-lock.  "Niagara-class systems" = [massively multi-threaded UltraSPARC T1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraSPARC_T1).  For "earlier SMP" they might mean earlier SPARC, or earlier systems in general with normal MESI that can take use a cache-lock for atomic CAS attempts.  Also note that they spin read-only, only even attempting to CAS if they see the lock unlocked.  I'm not sure exactly why backoff is still good in this case, or on which systems.

Comment: Probably read attempts (leading to MESI share requests) can disrupt an LL/SC CAS attempt on earlier SPARC CPUs, potentially leading to livelock if a core can't hold onto a line in Exclusive state between LL and SC.  Or at least slowdowns.

Comment: @PeterCordes _Probably read attempts (leading to MESI share requests) can disrupt an LL/SC CAS attempt on earlier SPARC CPUs_ Sounds like a reasonable idea. At least LL/SC pair can fail spuriously unlike CAS implementation on x86 which AFAIK can never fail for all the competing threads (at least one succeeds).

Comment: Yes, exactly, creating spurious failure is what I meant.  And yes, that's correct; x86 `lock cmpxchg` implements C++11 `compare_exchange_strong` - spurious failure impossible.

Comment: This [link](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/linux:lock.pdf) should shed some light. It should have to do with the number of MESI shares requested generated after a release: the time needed to satisfy one such request is then linear with the number of threads. By backing off we reduce the number of requests a single core needs to wait for. I'm not sure how old SMP systems where more affected by this than modern ones: probably a more decentralised architecture (i.e. links between the componentes, like the ring lanes, QPI lane or equivalent).